# Controller not found media model in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I tested to using laravel but i get some error unexpected, i already follows tutorial and some video. i think, i do it right. but i get this error. The problem controller not found media model.

> Class "App\Media" not found

Route

```
Route::get('/', [MediaController::class, 'index']);
```

MediaController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Media;

class MediaController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    return Media::all;
  }
}
```

Media model

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Media extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'media';
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $primaryKey = 'Media_ID';
}
```

Comment: duplicate of [Laravel 8 Error Class 'App\User' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009186/laravel-8-error-class-app-user-not-found). this is a namespace error.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon i try to follow bottom answer as duplicate that mentions. to add models bettween app and my model. It return Class "App\Models\Media" not found

Answer (score 1):

Your `use` statement for your `Media` model is incorrect. As of Laravel 8 the default namespace for models is `App\Models` where previously they where in the `App` namespace.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Media;

class MediaController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    return Media::all;
  }
}
```

Ensure that the `Media.php` file exists in your `app/Models` directory and is capitalised correctly.

Then in your `web.php` file, don't forget to include the use statement for your `MediaController` at the top.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MediaController;
```

Comment: please avoid answering duplicate questions.

Comment: now it return Class "App\Models\Media" not found

Comment: Does your `Media` model exist in the `app/Models` directory or is it in another directory?

Comment: @Unflux exists as Media.php in that directory.

Comment: @davidstephen I've added some more explination to my answer

Comment: I dont know what the problem here, I tried to install new laravel and just copy previous file. it works. As i know, i dont edit anything the first laravel installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

Your Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class MediaController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return Media::all;
    }
}
```

Your Route:

```
 Route::get('/', 'MediaController@index');
```